# CodeIgniter Database call in Model-Class

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model, fatal-error

I was looking around for this problem a lot! But nothing realy helped to solve this issue.

I always get the following error:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

I have the following Controller:

```
<?php
class Station extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct($params=array()) {
        parent::__construct();

        session_start();

        $this->load->library('parser');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->tpl_data['location'] = $this->stationmodel->getLocations()->all;
        $_SESSION['location'] = $this->tpl_data['location'];


        $this->load->view('station', $this->tpl_data);
    }
}
```

?>

And the following Model:

```
<?php
class StationModel extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getLocations() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE City_IATA = 'MUC'");
        var_dump($query);

        // Just for test purposes!
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->Location_Name_DE . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

In my autoload.php I load the database module:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Also when I try to load the database modul directly in the controller I will get the same error.

My database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '****';
$db['default']['database'] = 'comvel';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what returns the var_dump?

Comment: did you check your database settings?

Comment: The var_dump returns nothing, cause it dies before the var_dump.
The database settings are checked and fine :-/

Comment: How many results do you want query to fetch single or multiple if single then use $query->row()

Comment: I want multiple results. But my problem is, that the line

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE City_IATA = 'MUC'");

creates the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Comment: Try not to use the native sessions whilst using Codeigniter, you'll end up confusing things, and there's a lot more in the session class that you might use! http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: is the $db['default']['db_debug'] variable in config/database.php set to TRUE? There might be an error in your SQL query which as a result doesn't return an object.

Comment: Yes it is set to true. But I only receive the above error.

Comment: I edited my thread and added the database.php

Comment: Seems like the problem is solved!!
The problem was, that I edited the `CI_Model` for autocompletion in my Eclipse PTD. therefor I used the following article:

[link](http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2)

Seems like these changes messed up my CI_Model!

Thanks to all of you for your help!!


  [link](http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2)

Comment: No trouble! Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller try removing `$params=array()` from `function __construct($params=array())`

I would also remove the `__construct() {}` from your model as it doesn't do anything and might cause you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I Changed the __construct in the controller and removed the __construct from the model. But nothing changed. Still receiving the error.

Comment: Try var dumping `$this->db` before the `$this->db->query()` line.

Comment: The var_dump($this->db) return null. So the database isn't initialized. But the database module is set in the config/autload.php and the parameters in the config/database.php are also fine. Do I have to set anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird one. Seems like you've done everything right.

Have you tried removing the constructors altogether? My guess is that your constructor is somehow preventing your model from being initialized with the `db` object. If you need to run some initialization code, it may be more appropriate to use a [hook](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), such as the `pre_controller` hook.